# Unable to change default currency for in-app billing

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am currently adding items on my developer console, but I have encountered a problem. The problem is that google requires me to add a price for my own home country. In my case this is Norway with the currency NOK. I want the price to be equal in all countries including Norway, since I have hardcoded the price into my app.

I have still not found any setting on my developer console to "Change Default Currency" and based on [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html) I have to add a price for my own country. Another problem with just changing the NOK price around the current currency courses, is that the minimum price of USD is slightly lower then the NOK minimum price.

Is there any workaround to temporarly change the default currency?

Answer (score 4):

There is a way to set the price per country manually. What you need to do is set your USD minimum and then go and change the price manually one by one for the country's that complain.

Comment: Wouldn't that result in that all complaining countries will be adjusted into the NOK price based on todays currency courses?

Comment: Nope, that wont. You can choose to have your product cheaper in some countries and more expensive in others. Setup wise you can do it.

Comment: This kind of solved my problem, and I used this solution. But this makes most countries a bit more expensive then todays courses.

Comment: I know what you mean, but this is the "only" way to solve the issue. Frankly people dont care too much about costs in other companies. They either like your product or dislike it, nothing to do with costs. So be rest assured. This is the only way.

Comment: With two upvotes you get half the bounty. I call that fair and square.

Comment: Really!!! You are going to base the bounty on what the community thinks about my answer ? And not the fact that no one else responded to your answer, since I answered it accurately and correctly ? Not to mention the amount of hours you would have spent on trying to find a answer from the google documentation ? You call that fair ? And Square ?  Read up the FAQ for what is fair, you will be very surprised.